# Plot lineplot with a "year-less" date-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, tidyr

I have crime data of the years 2018-2020. Each row represents one crime. For the sake of this example let's assume that there are two variables `crimetype` (e.g. theft, robbery) and `date` (when the crime was committed).

Some sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(date= sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"),10000, replace=T),
                   crimetype = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100000, replace=T))
```

My goal is to create a lineplot for, let's say, type "A" crimes. On the x-axis there should be the date (from january 1st to december 31st), on the y-axis there should be the number of crimes per day. However, as I want the three lines (one for each year) to be shown on top of each other, so that I can compare them, there should be no year on the x-axis. Or it should not be displayed at least.

```
  ^        . . . . . .
  |     . .           .
  | . .                .
n |                      . 2018
  |      - - -
  | - - -      - - - - - 2019
  | = = =
  |       = = = = = = = = 2020
  |
  ------------------------------------->
   Jan-1                Dec-31
```

I was trying to create a new date-variable with all the dates in the same year (here 2020).

```
data <- data %>% mutate(daymonth = substr(date, 5, length(date)),
                        date_new = as.Date(paste("2020", daymonth, sep="")),
                        daymonth = NULL)
```

Is there a better way to do this and how can I plot the graph?

```
data_plot <- data %>% filter(crimetype == 'A')
ggplot(data = data_plot, aes(x = date_new, y = ?, color=format(date, "%Y")) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working with dates have a look at the `lubridate` package which I use here for extracting the year. Also you can get rid of the year by using `format(date, "%d-%m")`. The following approach is a bit of a hack. To use a date axis but still get rid of the year I set the year for all dates to 2018. The question of which variable to plot ... simply count the obs to get the number of crimes by date. Finally. I set the breaks of the date axis to 1 month. Adjust this as you like. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data <- data.frame(date= sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"),10000, replace=T),
                   crimetype = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100000, replace=T))

data_plot <- data %>%
  mutate(
    year = lubridate::year(date),
    year = factor(year),
    # A hack. Set year to 2018. Allows me to use a date axis
    date_foo = as.Date(paste(2018, format(date, "%m-%d"), sep = "-"))) %>% 
  filter(crimetype == 'A') %>% 
  count(date, date_foo, year, crimetype)

ggplot(data = data_plot, aes(x = date_foo, y = n, color = year, group = year)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%d-%m")
#> Warning: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>